# Algorithm for tracking relative trends

Tags: algorithm, statistics, trend

I'm working on a website with **articles** and **tags** (their relationship is **n:m**). An important part of the website is filtering the articles by tag. The tags have certain **weights**, representing their relative importance. The weights change over time (on a daily basis), depending on how often they were used for filtering articles (**hits**)).

What algorithm should I use to calculate the weights? Key criteria:

- Based on historical data (hits), but pretty short term (~ last 10-20
  days)
- The relevance of past data goes down over time (hits from
  yesterday are more important than hits from 10 days ago)
- Respecting the "individual trend" of tags (a tag that went from 100
  to 200 hits within a day wins over a tag that had 200 hits two days in a
  row)
- Respect new tags (with no historical hits)
- Respect tags that didn't get many hits in the last couple of days (tags with high weights will naturally get more hits so "weaker" tags should still get a shot to "break the circle" every once in a while)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following formula for tag weight:

```
Score = c1 * Hits(today) + c2 * (Hits(today) - Hits(yesterday)) + c3 * Random
Weight = a * Score + (1 - a) * Weight(yesterday)
```

Where

- Random - random value 0..1
- c1, c2, c3, a - appropriate constant values, `0<a<1`